# Opencart: Remove page ID path from URL

Tags: url, redirect, opencart

I'm trying to make my site more SEO friendly and I' noticing that whenever I go to an product through either a tag or a different page (2,3,4 ect) that it adds it to the URL.

For example:

www.wisdomsurvival.com/Guardian-Survival-kit/culinary-can-of-preparedness-seeds.html?page=2

I would like to remove ?page=2 from the path

Opencart 1.5.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: My main goal is to have one URL for each page instead of multiple paths. For example:
http://www.wisdomsurvival.com/person-guardian-preparedness-package-camping-bug-out
http://www.wisdomsurvival.com/camping-and-bug-out/person-guardian-preparedness-package-camping-bug-out

The first URL is a direct link, the second comes from clicking from a category, the third (not shown because I can only post 2 links) comes from clicking from a subcategory and the fourth (also not shown) from a manufacturer list.

I need to have them all either redirect to the first URL or just go directly to the first URL without redirecting, along with any other URLS such as the ones that have the page ID path or tag path.

Answer (score 1):

I recognise that theme :-)

Where is the ?page=2 coming from as the link works perfectly without it. You need to trace the source of the link. First try the template views and see if it is a simple link edit in the layout that will accomplish what you need.

If not you may find the information is coded in the controller if it is being dynamically generated. Again you should be able to edit the code that generates the link there.

If not you may find that it is in a model that is being called. Again, just find the model and edit the link structure you find there.

The url on your page will only be a reflection of the url you generated somewhere else in order for the link to be followed in the first place.

Usually when I am building with opencart I find the theme modules are often not coded very well in terms of SEO. Fortunately with opencart these things are usually very easy to remedy.

Top trick -> I often stick additional bits into my urls that have no impact on the page generated but Google picks up on as keywords anyway.

If you post your code if you are having problems reformatting the link formats I will have a look for you,

Hope that helps,

Paul.

Comment: I'm not too well versed in coding. For example this url: http://www.wisdomsurvival.com/start-burn-unit-first-aid-kits.html?filter_tag=survival   comes from clicking on the product on this page http://www.wisdomsurvival.com/index.php?route=product/search&filter_tag=survival

Comment: Hi Paul, from which controller file should I posted the code?